# How to check if content of element is empty and if so, remove that element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to select any h2 element inside of a certain div that does not have content in it and remove it. This is my html code:

```
 <div class="skipToContainer">
     <h2 class="vidSkipTo">Hello </h2>
     <h2 class="vidSkipTo"></h2>
     <h2 class="vidSkipTo"></h2>
     <h2 class="vidSkipTo"></h2>
 </div>
```

These are a couple jQuery codes I have tried to no avail:

```
jQuery(".skipToContainer .vidSkipTo").each (function () {
    if (jQuery(this).text().trim() === '')
        jQuery(this).remove();
}

jQuery(".skipToContainer h2").each (function () {
    if (jQuery(this).text().trim() === '')
        jQuery(this).remove();
}

jQuery(".skipToContainer h2").each (function () {
    if (jQuery(this).text() === '')
        jQuery(this).remove();
}
```

Any suggestions?

*Note: I'm doing these tests on a local WordPress site. Not sure if that matters but just to let you know.*

Comment: I noticed you didn't close the jQuery functions with `});`

Comment: you have a syntax error... no closing `)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tb93k9t8/1/

Comment: @SamuelLiew, note that another `}` would actually create a *new* syntax error. (See my formatting, it's a bit clearer.)

Comment: wow thank you. I've been looking at code for so long that I missed that, lol.

Comment: @Jason yes.. I think so... unless you want to use the empty selector given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
jQuery(".skipToContainer h2").filter(":empty").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
 <div class="skipToContainer">

          <h2 class="vidSkipTo">Hello </h2>
          <h2 class="vidSkipTo"></h2>
          <h2 class="vidSkipTo"></h2>
          <h2 class="vidSkipTo"></h2>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.skipToContainer > .vidSkipTo:empty').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skipToContainer">
     <h2 class="vidSkipTo">Hello </h2>
     <h2 class="vidSkipTo"></h2>
     <h2 class="vidSkipTo"></h2>
     <h2 class="vidSkipTo"></h2>
 </div>
```